# elasticsearch / tire how to correctly return default recordset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

What would be the best way to approach the return of a default recordset? If no search results are returned. Currently using below code but it feels not the correct way.

```
def self.search(params)

      puts "SEARCH PARAM ="
      puts params

      if params
        tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20, :default_operator => 'AND', :use_dis_max => true) do
          query do
            boolean do
              must { string 'gamers:2' } if params[:gamers] == "2"
              must { string 'gamers:4' } if params[:gamers] == "4"
            end
          end
          to_curl
        end
      else
        puts "search params not found"
        @gamers = Gamers.where(:level => "rookie")
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you're only putting in the default set when no params are passed in vs when no search results are returned.

I'd get the results of search and check that **!results.total.zero?**, then pull the default set accordingly